# Transposing a matrix in Java but encountering errors

Tags: java, matrix, transpose

I have to ensure that I read in a text file(input) and transpose the matrix whereby the rows become columns.

Sample input:

```
2 4
abcd/
efgh
```

(whereby 2 indicates row and 4 indicates column and / indicates new line)
and output should look like:

```
ae/
bf/
cg/
dh
```

This is my code:

```
import java.util.*;

public class Transpose {
    private void run() {
        Scanner scan=new Scanner(System.in);
        int Row= scan.nextInt();
        int Col=scan.nextInt();
        char[][] arr=new char[Row][Col];
        for(int i=0;i<Row;i++){
            for(int j=0;j<Col;j++){
                arr[i][j]=scan.next().charAt(0);
            }
        }
        for(int j=0;j<Col;j++){
            for(int i=0;i<Row;i++){
                System.out.print(arr[i][j]);
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Transpose newTranspose = new Transpose();
        newTranspose.run();
    }
}
```

However, I am getting the error:
programme crashed/producing non-zero exit code
Is this a runtime error and how can I go about fixing this.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please edit your post and copy/paste your code instead of posting a picture with code, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
int Row = scan.nextInt();
int Col = scan.nextInt();
scan.nextLine();    // skip newline.
char[][] arr = new char[Row][Col];
for (int i = 0; i < Row; i++) {
    String line = scan.nextLine();
    for (int j = 0; j < Col; j++) {
        arr[i][j] = line.charAt(j);
    }
}
for (int j = 0; j < Col; j++) {
    for (int i = 0; i < Row; i++) {
        System.out.print(arr[i][j]);
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

input:

```
2 4
abcd
efgh
```

output:

```
ae
bf
cg
dh
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! This code worked for me! Just for clarification I observe that u added scanned every line and then indexed it to get the characters which I missed out. Is that why my code may not work?

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
public class Transpose {
    private void run() {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Row");
        int Row = scan.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Col");
        int Col = scan.nextInt();
        char[][] arr = new char[Row][Col];
        for (int i = 0; i < Row; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < Col; j++) {
                System.out.println("Enter character");
                arr[i][j] = scan.next().charAt(0);
            }
        }
        for (int j = 0; j < Col; j++) {
            for (int i = 0; i < Row; i++) {
                System.out.println(arr[i][j] + " ");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Transpose newTranspose = new Transpose();
        newTranspose.run();
    }
}
```

With desired output